# Assembly*Attributes missing in Release builds on Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, .net-assembly

Every component of my app-suite specifies the following in `AssemblyInfo.cs` to identify itself:

```
..
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("MM.nnn.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyTitle( "Component Title" )]
#if DEBUG
[assembly: AssemblyDescription( "<Component>.Debug" )]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration( "Debug" )]
#else
[assembly: AssemblyDescription( "<Component>.Release" )]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration( "Release" )]
#endif
```

Every component's start-up usually involves the following sequence:

```
Assembly        asm =   Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly( );
FileVersionInfo fvi =   FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo( asm.Location );

Utils.sModInfo =    string.Format( Utils.scFmtModId, fvi.FileDescription, fvi.Comments,
                        fvi.FileVersion, Utils.GetBuildFromVersion( fvi.FileVersion ) );
```

For completeness:

```
/// <summary>Returns build-date/time, extracted from the version string
    (use on 'MM.nnn.*'-versioned assemblies)</summary>
public static DateTime  GetBuildFromVersion( string sVersion )
{
    DateTime    dB =    new DateTime( 2000, 1, 1 );
    string[]    sa =    sVersion.Split( '.' );

    if(  sa.Length == 4  )
    {
        dB =    dB.AddDays(    Convert.ToInt32( sa[ 2 ] ) );
        dB =    dB.AddSeconds( Convert.ToInt32( sa[ 3 ] ) << 1 );
    }
    return  dB;
}
```

Now, Xamarin.Android project shares a lot of library code, and i would like to use same approaches for similar conceptual tasks.  Therefore, i created `AssemblyInfo.cs`, and filled it accordingly..

Everything works great in `Debug` builds:  attributes are retrieved and displayed properly.
The very first `Release` build crashed, unable to get `asm.Location` - as i later figured out.
So i put `#if DEBUG .. #endif` around that code and went on..

---

Today i realized `FileVersionInfo` is not really necessary, and changed Android start-up to:

```
string  sVersion =  asm.GetName( ).Version.ToString( ),
        sFileDsc =  string.Empty,
        sComment =  string.Empty;

foreach(  Attribute attr in asm.GetCustomAttributes( true )  )
{
    if(  attr.GetType( ) == typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute)  )
        sFileDsc =      ((AssemblyTitleAttribute)attr).Title;
    else
    if(  attr.GetType( ) == typeof(AssemblyDescriptionAttribute)  )
        sComment =      ((AssemblyDescriptionAttribute)attr).Description;
}

Utils.sModInfo =    string.Format( Utils.scFmtModId, sFileDsc, sComment,
                        sVersion, Utils.GetBuildFromVersion( sVersion ) );
```

This worked perfectly in `Debug` build..  And only gave me a version# in `Release` one!

Exposing proper (*similar* and *comparable* to all other components) version# is great, i'll take that.
But **what happens to the rest of `Assembly*Attributes` in `Release` builds**?

Comment: Similar kind of problem as getting a crash from asm.Location.  It gets fuzzy where exactly code lives in a Release build.  A basic optimization used by the jtiter is *inlining* code.   Moving the code of a method into the caller of the method.  A method that is sensitive to the location, like any that would call Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), needs the [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] attribute so it is not allowed to be moved.

Comment: Well, to a point i can see a problem with `asm.Location`, as Release build gets installed into an unknown [to me yet] place on Android.. Still, it DOES sit in *some folder* - why not return *that*?
So what, JIT makes Attributes "optimizable-removable"? Are they treated as debug metadata? Why aren't they removed in Release builds on Windows?